# How to pass data from html client to NodeJS server?

Tags: html, node.js

I would like to send some data from client to NodeJS server using POST method.
Below is my part of html code.

```html
<form action="http://localhost:8080/data/name/:name/ssn/:ssn" method="post" id="signup">
    <h1>Personal info post example</h1>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your fullname" />
        <small></small>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="ssn">SSN:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ssn" placeholder="Enter your SSN" />
        <small></small>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button><br><br>
</form>
```

Below is my part of `server.js`.
I tried to print out everything that I can think of what I can.
I wrote down the results as comments as well.
This is the result when I enter 'a' for the name and 'b' for the ssn and submit it.

```
app.post('/data/name/:name/ssn/:ssn', function(req, res) {
    console.log('req.query: ', req.query); // {}
    console.log('req.query.name: ',req.query.name); // undefined
    console.log('req.query.ssn: ',req.query.ssn); // undefined
    console.log('req.params: ',req.params); // { name: ':name', ssn: ':ssn' }
    console.log('req.params.name: ',req.params.name); // :name
    console.log('req.params.ssn: ',req.params.ssn); // :ssn
});
```

When I type 'a' and 'b' into search boxes and hit the submit button, the web browser starting to load but never ends and my VSC shows the result.
Can anyone help me what I need to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you're mixing `req.params` and `req.query`, while you actually need `req.body`

try this:

add this to server.js (you need to install body-parser):

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/data', function(req, res) {
    console.log('req.body: ', req.body);

    const {name, ssn} = req.body;
    console.log('name: ', name);
    console.log('ssn: ', ssn);
    res.json(req.body);
});
```

and change HTML form (add `name` attribute, that's your data):

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/data" method="post" id="signup">
    <h1>Personal info post example</h1>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your fullname" />
        <small></small>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="ssn">SSN:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ssn" name="ssn" placeholder="Enter your SSN" />
        <small></small>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I want. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

your code is good. But you are facing this problem because the server is not sending any data after submit.

First, there should be something to handle GET:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile('index.html');
    console.log('Someone saw your website!');
})

app.listen(80);
```

Secondly, return something after submit:

```
app.post('/data/name/:name/ssn/:ssn', function(req, res) {
    console.log('req.query: ', req.query); // {}
    console.log('req.query.name: ',req.query.name); // undefined
    console.log('req.query.ssn: ',req.query.ssn); // undefined
    console.log('req.params: ',req.params); // { name: ':name', ssn: ':ssn' }
    console.log('req.params.name: ',req.params.name); // :name
    console.log('req.params.ssn: ',req.params.ssn); // :ssn
    res.end('Thankyou, \n Your Name:'+req.params.name+'\n Your Ssn:'+req.params.ssn);
});
```

Comment: I tried it and it shows 'Thankyou!' on the website when I submitted it. But on the serverside terminal, 'a' and 'b' is not still showing so I cannot handle the variables on the server side. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: when I type "http://localhost:8080/data/name/a/ssn/b" on the url search box in the browser, I can see the result on the server side terminal. but it is still not showing the result when I use submit button.

Comment: Hi, did you mean on the client side? Check the new code 